# retrieve data from more than two tables using hibernateTemplate

Tags: hibernate, spring-mvc

I am new to Spring, Hibernate environment. I have two tables t1, t2 also having two POJO objects for t1 and t2. I need to retrive all the data from two tables using Hibernate Template. Please anyone give answer. Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1):

Call this one:

```
protected List findAll(Class clazz) {
    return getHibernateTemplate().find("from " + clazz.getName());
}
```

This function will return you a list of object.

updated:

```
String hql="SELECT T.* FROM TEST T, STUDENT S WHERE S.DNO=? AND S.CLASS_ID=T.CLS_ID AND T.STATUS='A' AND T.BATCH=S.BATCH AND T.SHIFT=S.SHIFT";
List list = getHibernateTemplate.find(hql,"condition");
```

Comment: SELECT T.* FROM TEST T, STUDENT S WHERE S.DNO=? AND S.CLASS_ID=T.CLS_ID AND T.STATUS='A' AND T.BATCH=S.BATCH AND T.SHIFT=S.SHIFT, I want to use this query in my HibernateTemplate Object.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have the hbm files/annotated pojo and Spring properly configured, you could file an SQL query using session.createSQLQuery(sqlQuery) for selecting data from both the tables(If you want this at one shot) . You would get an Object[] in the result which you could use . Else you could fire separate queries as subodh recommends.

check [here](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/querysql.html) for a reference.

```
        return this.getHibernateTemplate().execute(new HibernateCallback<List>() {

        @Override
        public List doInHibernate(Session session) throws HibernateException, SQLException {

            String sqlQuery = "yourQueryHere";
            SQLQuery query = session.createSQLQuery(sqlQuery);
            List lstData = query.list();

            for (Object row : lstData) {
                Object[] recordArray = (Object[]) row;
                //recordArray[1] , recordArray[2] will give the columns

            }



        }
    });
```

or instead of callback you could use

```
this.getHibernateTemplate().getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession()
```

to get the session object . Note as of Spring 3.0 using hibernate template is not recommended. You can just inject the sessionFactory, get the session from there and use it .